# Compare strings and copy difference

Tags: c#, string, copy, comparison

I have one master string that I control, call it string A. Then I have another ever-changing string outside of my control, call it string B. I need A to contain everything that was ever in B, in the correct order.

**This is how B behaves:** In the beginning, new text appears from top to bottom (the way text would normally appear if you wrote a word document). Then, at a random point, it wraps and new text starts from the top again, overwriting what was there before.

If it wasn't for the fact that B wrapped and started at top after a certain number of bytes had been written, I could have copied the entire string at given intervals with a timer. Instead, I have to use some kind of comparison, that compares B to A from top to bottom. When it finds a byte in B that is different from A, it should copy from B everything from that point on to the end, and write it to the bottom of A.

In case the behviour is unclear, I have typed out an example below. Any code-examples of how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
String B: abc
String A: abc

String B: abcde
String A: abcde

String B: fgh
String A: abcdefgh

String B: fghijk
String A: abcdefghijk

etc...
```

**Just to add my own thoughts on solutions:** I tried to use a cursor approach to solve it, but it broke when the text wrapped to top. I was not sure how to do the comparison approach. I looked into String.Compare, but it only returns whether it is larger or smaller. I guess i could do a byte by byte comparison, manually, but that seems like it would be incredibly inefficient, especially when the strings become very large.

**EDIT (clarification):** If text appears in B, that has appeared in B before, it should still be included in A.

**EDIT (clarification 2):** Just to be clear, I am not able to control the process that holds string B, I am forced to regularly poll it (either with a timer or with a really fast loop).

Magnus

Comment: Well, I have written a program with a few thousand lines of code, that reads lots of stuff out of memory of another process, including what I call string B above. I tried to use a cursor approach to solve it, but it broke when the text wrapped to top. I was not sure how to do the comparison approach. I looked into String.Compare, but it only returns whether it is larger or smaller. I guess i could do a byte by byte comparison, manually, but that seems like it would be incredibly inefficient, especially when the strings become very large.

Comment: what if the next string change results in "flmno". Should the f be ignored (i.e. how to handle duplicates)?

Comment: What happens if B becomes something it  has already been, like "abc" again after your example? Should "abc" then be appended to A, or is it enough that it has already been included once? And then what if B becomes "defg"? In other words, does "bcdef" in A encompass both of "bcd", and "def" in B, or should they be counted as two different words?

Comment: Good question. f should then be included because sometime it might be the case that new additions are equal to what was before

Comment: Guys, great question there from @Kjartan and Default. It might be the case that text that existed before, comes again. It should then be added to A again, and not ignored.

Comment: @Anders Great answer. You just defined your question as impossible to achieve. Not without "cooperation" of either the process being monitored, or "divine intervention" by a preemptive OS that suspends it for your observations.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks very appealing @Default, thank you. Let me give it a try and get back to you. For those who down-voted: I added clarification and ideas I had thought of. Great if you could remove down-vote or let me know what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: [seems to work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/25F1VX).. I agree with sehe though, miss some reads and the A string would be corrupt.

Comment: @Anders I haven't downvoted (it's clear enough as it is) but your question asks for hacky solutions that can not possibly made to work "correctly". You're free to tinker, but since you apparently haven't realized that all you can achieve this way is _hacks_ it's a waste of anybodies time to answer it for you.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a question involving what you /really/ want to achieve (not ***how***, because down the path you've chosen lies madness). Chances are always good someone knows the /sane/ way to achieve that goal ([What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: I appreciate the insight gents. I did not think of it as hacky or not, it is just a problem I have been faced with that I have been trying to find a solution to over the last few days, but if it isn't possible to solve, then that might be why I haven't figured it out hehe. I have to think a bit more about what you say before I understand it though, my head seems to be a bit slow on this. Thanks again. PS: @sehe I am not able to control the process that holds string B, I have to regularly poll it (either with a timer or with a really fast loop).

Comment: @Anders That's fine. You just have to realize you cannot be 100% sure you don't misrepresent that data. So, don't use this approach for anything mission critical. If you add this insight to the question (perhaps instead of the more fuzzy explanations), you would have a better question (I'll +1 then)

Comment: @sehe Got it, done. Now I will try to implement Kjartan's algorithm, looks exciting :)

Answer (score 1):

**Basic idea for an algorithm:**

Check backwards from the end of A minus the length of B, versus the beginning of B, to remove from B what has already been added, then add the rest to A.

This should append each "word" from B to the end of A, minus any part of B that happens to overlap with the last part of A (I *hope* I've interpreted the problem more or less correctly).

**Example:** Say B is "DEFGH" and so far, A has logged: "ABCDEF".

An algorithm for comparing would then iterate as follows:

```
  D - - - -  // Only check D first, from end of A - length(B)
A B C D E F  // No match!

    D - - - -  // Move B ahead 1, still no match
A B C D E F 

      D - - - -  // Move B ahead 1, one match now.
A B C D E F
```

Result:

- If the rest of A matches the corresponding chars of B, then you can just append the rest of B to A.
- If there is a mismatch between the rest of A and the overlapping characters in B, then start the algorithm again, but this time beginning from after the previous match.

Example of mismatch:

```
      D E F L M N O ...
A B C D X Y D E F
```

Here, `E` and `F` in B will mismatch with `X` and `Y` in A, so start over by comparing `D` in B to `X`, then `Y`, etc, until you reach the second `D` in A. At that point, you will find matches for `D E F` in A, while the rest of B (`L M N O`) are ready to be appended to A.

Comment: Kjartan, thanks a lot! We are from the same country :) Jeg studerte paa NTNU. Will try to understand this, then implement it.

Comment: Ok, glad to help! Hope it works. Lykke til! :)